# Reliable way to get the kernel structs sizes in PHP

Tags: php, linux, struct

I have to parse binary datas provided by the Linux kernel. These binary datas are some classic data structures used in the kernel.

For example, I need to parse a struct where the first value is a `timeval` struct. In the kernel source code, it is defined as:

```
struct timeval {
        __kernel_time_t         tv_sec;         /* seconds */
        __kernel_suseconds_t    tv_usec;        /* microseconds */
};
```

So I have to know the size of `__kernel_time_t` and `__kernel_suseconds_t`.

`__kernel_time_t` is defined as: `typedef long __kernel_time_t`, it is a long.

Since I have to parse these binary structs (in a string) in PHP with `unpack()` (yes, I know I have strange ideas), I have to retrieve the size of the kernel integer sizes.

How can I achieve that? An embedded and JiT-compiled C program that executes sizeofs? Retrieving the compilation configuration with `gcc` or `getconf` commands? What's the best and the more portable way to do that, and is it necessary to implement a fallback system (eg. using getconf if C compilation is not available)?

Comment: PHP isn't really suited to manipulating binary data directly.  Maybe it would be advisable to write some simple tool in a language such as C that would parse the binary file into something more easily processed in PHP suck as a CSV text file

Comment: Agreed, but using `unpack()` is not so difficult once you know the integers/structs sizes. And the problem is still the same with a more sophisticated C program: I still need  to embed this into a PHP code because the feature I'm trying to develop is part of a greater PHP application. Currently I'm trying to write an embedded C program that dumps sizeof of the needed structs/scalar types. That works fine, but if there is anything cleaner (or if you have ideas of fallbacks if gcc isn't available), I'm interested.

Comment: The cleaner way is to write a php extension.

Comment: Ahah, it seems a little overcomplicated compared to my original needs, but it is a good occasion to learn how to write a PHP ext =)
I'm still opened to tips & suggestions. Unless a programmagical solution arrives, I will use my embedded C code or write a simple C extension. Thanks you two.

Answer (score 0):

You have not explained what are you really trying to do and as a result your question seems ambiguous. What do you mean by

> I have to parse binary datas provided by the Linux kernel. These binary datas are some classic data structures used in the kernel.

Do you need to interpret stuff returned from syscalls **or** some internal kernel structures?

If the former, you can just go with that crap solution of compiling stuff and checking out the result. But you want **userspace** headers. If the latter, you need debug symbols for the kernel and you don't want to parse that yourself anyway. Tools like crash (debugger) can do that for you.

Comment: These binary datas are read from the "Linux API". Just now, I'm trying to parse that : https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt (go to section *5. Event interface*). Since it is a "public API" and not a strange dump from a syscall, I thought it was parseable by any other language.